# Is there any way to add branching into logic app by doing copy paste?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to add around 5 branches into my current logic app but i dont find anything like i can copy paste all the steps.

Is there any way ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to code view and copy paste all the steps, you will have to change the `name` of all the actions and also change all the `run after action`